# Facebook like not worked on non english domain

Tags: facebook, joomla, facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins

Good day!

I have a website which based on Joomla 2.5 and use 2 domains english as mirror and cyrillic as primary. On half pages Facebook Like button works normal ([example page](http://proved-partner.ru/customs/7568-segodnya-deystvie-mdp-mb-otmeneno-na-kavkaze.html)), but the other half does not work ([example page](http://proved-partner.ru/economy/7574-lokalizaciya-parallelnogo-importa-finansoviy-risk-dlya-investora.html)).

I see the following error: *Could not resolve object at URL http://провэд.рф/testpages.html*, the domain name should been translated *from провэд.рф to xn--b1ae2adf4f.xn--p1ai*.

What is interesting, the problem appeared a couple of months ago.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good Day!

I'm resolve this problem by using Open Graph. In all articles I'm set url with link on english domain in og:url property:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://proved-partner.ru/this-article-url.html">
```

And changed code of like button on the next:

```
<fb:like show_faces="true" send="false" layout="button_count" 
    href="http://proved-partner.ru{link}"
    width="300">                    
</fb:like>
```